# Lazy @ModelAttribute in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, model, annotations

Is there such thing like lazy model attrubute annotation in spring?

below peace of code to explain what im looking for

```
@Controller
class MyController {
    private boolean hasValue=false;

@RequestMapping(value "test.html")
public String testMEthod(ModelMap model, @RequestParam(value = "person", defaultValue = "null") Person person)
    person==null ? false : true;
    return "testResults";
}

@ModelAttribute("hasValue")
public boolean hasValue(){
     return hasValue;
}
```

code above will always put false to model, because all @ModelAttribute are executed before calling any @RequestMapping. To work, it would need force to put hasValue to model after method called from request mapping.

Comment: How did you solve this?

Comment: If i remember it right, i gave up and did that something like loading function below.

Answer (score 0):

With the default `@ModelAttribute` annotation, like you have mentioned the @ModelAttribute methods will get evaluated before the `@RequestMapping` annotated methods. Probably two ways to do it lazily would be the following:

a. Explicit, have a method which sets your model attributes post method call, call it from your @RequestMapping methods:

```
public void setLazyModelAttribs(Model model){
     model.addAttribute("hasValue", hasValue);
}


@RequestMapping
public void testMethod(..Model model, ...){
    //normal request mapping
    setLazyModelAttribs(model);
}
```

b. Doing it using `after` aspectj advice.

Comment: i was looking for method to simplify loading that specific model attribute, so its its not what i was looking for. Probably, ill have to add this to model in normal way :(

Comment: Okay, yes probably I misunderstood the question then, can you please again explain why you are looking for the value to be loaded lazily, how does loading it before the method call affect anything?

Comment: As in example, value of field can be changed in code called by request mapping. what made me looking for lazy method is fact, that i call several method in code during request mapping, and in few of them value can be changed, so to solve this, i should do one of two: pass model to each to this methods(id like to avoid that because it doesn't feel right) or put it to model after calling methods, before returning view or redirect info, but this method splices operation in very distant lines of code. Lazy model attribute would be perfect in such situations.